Notation for Raising and Lowering indices does not agree with matrix multiplication?
I saw this equation in my book that raises the indices of a tensor $F_{\alpha \beta}$ like so: $F^{\mu \nu}=\eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}$. I do not know if this is the right way to think of this expression, but the way I understand it, its just a multiplication of matrices, which in fact should have the second index of the first matrices equal to the first index of the second matrix. Can you please explain what's going on here?

When I first learned index notation I thought the same way until I gave it up to think in terms of matrix multiplication. What "matrix" is the Riemann tensor $R^i{}{ijk},?$ Just take that the expression $\eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta}F{\alpha \beta}$ is a double sum where the ugly $\Sigma$ has been dropped.

Its in fact $$\star   F \  = \ (\star \eta)  \ F \  (\star \eta) ^T $$ with $F$ the components of an antisymmetric 2-form, the differential of the vector potential $A = A_\mu \ dx^\mu$. $\eta = \eta_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu\otimes dx^\nu$ is the metrics as a symmetric bilinear function on tangent vectors, $\star \eta = \left( \eta^{-1} \right)^{\mu \nu} e_\mu\otimes e_\nu$ the inverse metrics on linear forms and $\star F$ is the antisymmetric  bilinear form for pairs of vectors forming an rectangle. Einstein notation is commutative and very easy to perform, as opposed to the algebraic formulation.

@RolandF do you really want to say that $\eta^{\mu \alpha}\eta^{\nu \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}$ is undefined when $F$ is not antisymmetric?

No. But the Einstein-Maxwell formulas with the the letters $F$, $\eta$ is pinned in mathematical physics to the electromagnetic field in flat Minkowski space.

@RolandF this was not OP's question. In isolation your comment only confuses a beginner.

No, its your first comment, that is confusing. The Riemann tensor is a 2-form with matrix valued components in the Lie algebra of basis transformations in the tangent space $$R= \left(R^i_k\right)_{l m} \ dx^l \wedge dx^m $$

@RolandF I hope you agree that the Riemann tensor is not a matrix and therefore matrix multiplication from linear algebra is not too helpful when we apply index calculus to it.

You can think of a mixed tensor like ${X^j}i$ as a matrix; it is a very bad idea to think of a second order covariant tensor like $F{\alpha\beta}$ or a second order contravariant tensor like the metric tensor $\eta^{\mu\alpha}$ as a matrix.  Under a change of basis a matrix $X$ transforms as $L^{-1}XL$ where $L$ is the matrix that relates the two bases. Under a change of basis a second order covariant tensor $F$ transforms as $L^\top F L $.  Have a look at this video at 1:57:00.

It is basically a matrix multiplication. First note that the expressions with indices are components of the tensor i.e. just numbers so you can change the order of their multiplication. Just move the second $\eta$ to the right side of $F$. Then it's almost the normal expression for matrix multiplication except that the indices of the second $\eta$ are swapped. But that's just the same as a transpose. So you're multiplying $F$ by $\eta$ from the left side and its transpose from the right side.

So this only works because $\eta = \eta^T$, isn't it? No other conceptual detail I'm missing?

Well, the formula is at least well-formed even if $\eta$ isn't symmetric. However, using it to raise the indices suggests that it's a metric tensor which would mean that it's symmetric.
